# redirect from google calendar api after authentication to an angular route, problem with ? in url

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, google-calendar-api

In the process of allowing my app to access a google calendar from cloud functions, the user has to get a code to allow me to retrieve the token.
For this the user has to authenticate and allow, after this the user is redirected to a url that I provide. To this redirect the code is added in form of https://myapp.web.app/myroute?code=someCode&scope

https://myapp.web.app/myroute is a route of an angular app. But it seems that the router cannot handle this and brings following error:
Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'myroute'

Is there way to have the angular router handle this?
I'm on angular 6.0.8

I get the error:

Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'myroute'

at ApplyRedirects.push../node_modules/@angular/router/fesm5/router.js.ApplyRedirects.noMatchError (router.js:1382) [angular]

in the app-routing.module.ts I have:

```
imports ...

const routes: Routes = [
{ path: 'myroute/:someInfo',     component: myRouteComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
{ path: 'someOtherRoute',     component: someOtherComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

I think that the problem is that the angular router cannot handle the urls with ? as a separator.

I would be glad to have your opinion.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What does your code look like that doesn't work? Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Of course Angular can handle query params ! :)

The issue is coming from your route definition:

```
{ path: 'myroute/:someInfo',     component: myRouteComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
```

Will match `myroute/anything-else` but not `myroute`. If you want to also match `myroute` use something like this :

```
const routes: Routes = [
{ path: 'myroute/:someInfo',     component: myRouteComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
{ path: 'myroute',     component: myRouteComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
{ path: 'someOtherRoute',     component: someOtherComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]}
];
```

**Edit:**
In your component, you will have to subscribe to `ActivatedRoute` to retrieve the code
https://angular.io/guide/router#activated-route

Comment: THANK YOU mickdev!
I knew there is a way. Will try tomorrow.